# What's the advantage and use of prepared statements in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)
>   [prepared statements - are they necessary*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380657/prepared-statements-are-they-necessary)

Recently, heard about php prepared statements. Nearly all hi-rep php developers use php prepared statements. Can anyone explain me what's the main advantage and use of php prepared statements?

Comment: Are you asking about `Prepared statements`?

Comment: probably you are talking about **prepared statements** which are not *php statements*

Comment: yes exactly that's what i'm talking 'bout

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepared statements allow you to make multiple similar queries more efficiently. You can prepare (for example) an insert statement, then loop over it with multiple bits of data and get a performance boost as the database has less work to do as it doesn't have to set it up each time.

As a side effect, people using prepared statements tend to use bound parameters too, and these provide [protection from SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175948/do-prepare-statements-secure-your-database/7175992#7175992).

Comment: A good programmer should avoid running multiple similar queries, shouldn't they?