# Prepared statements in PDO; benefit over other forms of SQL insertion?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I learned in school to do something like the below to insert data into SQL via `$_POST`ed form data.

```
$title = mysql_escape_string($_POST["newstitle"]);
$body = mysql_escape_string($_POST["newsbody"]);
$addnews = $db->query("
    INSERT INTO news
        VALUES (CURRENT_DATE, '$body', '$title', '')
");
```

However, it was fairly recently I was told I should be using the below instead:

```
$addnews = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO news
        VALUES (CURRENT_DATE, :body, :title, '')
");
$addnews->execute(array(
    ':body' => $_POST["newsbody"],
    ':title' => $_POST["newstitle"]));
```

What benefit does the second snippet of code offer? My professor in the aforementioned course was very traditional and I imagine was teaching an archaic way of doing things. He did use a lot of PDO, but never for the above example. And yes, I know `mysql_escape_string()` is deprecated, but that is how I was taught. I'm trying to make an effort to change my method to be more appropriate for current trends.

Comment: Prepared statements. Other one is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: What you ought to have been using before was `mysql_REAL_escape_string()`. Prepared statements (with bound parameters!) are just more convenient. The added security is just a by-product over the easier-to-forget escaping (or using the wrong function).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the advantage and use of prepared statements in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568728/whats-the-advantage-and-use-of-prepared-statements-in-php)

Comment: @mario : Thankyou! The first level headed answer to this question i've heard in a while.

Comment: @mario, thank you, but that other question doesn't particularly answer my own. It can be more efficient for multiple insertions, but in the case of only having one, is there really a point if not just to keep things consistent?

@Dachi, even if I use `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: Well, `mysql_*` has been deprecated like you know, and `mysqli`, its replacement, has prepared statments. So there's no reason not to use them.

Comment: @riista - I use prepared statements even for a single statement. I think it makes my code more consistent and therefore easier to maintain. I know there's a loss of efficiency, but I think it's worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question can be answered easily.

I hope you understand that whatever value have to be properly formatted to be put into SQL query. So prepared statement does. Unlike whatever *_escape_string, which does only **partial** formatting, prepared statement intended to do the **full** one. And right where it have to be done - not sooner, not later - so it makes it impossible to forget. That's the point.

You only need to understand the difference between formatting and escaping, which no professor ever understands.