# What is my error when creating 4th AJAX populated dropdown using mySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

index.php
Hello community. I am using a dropdown list populated from mySQL using AJAX. I got this script as my base from a **[website](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html)** that a member of this community suggested  and you can see the demo **[here](http://roshanbh.com.np/dropdown/)**

In the demo there are 3 dropdowns and I am trying to make it 4, without luck as you can see in the screenshot here

[image]

I can not get the 2010 and pass it to the year so the 4th dropdown to show the selected rows, so it is shown as undefined.

*One note though,* if from the file findEngine.php remove the `AND model_year='$yearId'` and leave it with only 1 `AND`, it shows all the rows found for AUDI, not with the selected model or year of course.

I added the source codes below and the index.php to an external service because of it's length.

Any help is appreciate for this, I guess it is a beginners problem but I can not see it..

**index.php**
http://codepad.org/k3n7HJ4G

**findModel.php**

```
    <? 
    $make=$_GET['make'];
    mysql
    $query="SELECT distinct model_name FROM cars WHERE model_make_id='$make' order by model_name asc";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    ?>
    <select name="model" onchange="getyear('<?=$make?>',this.value)">
    <option>Select Model</option>
    <? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['model_name']?>><?=$row['model_name']?></option>
    <? } ?>
    </select>
```

**findYear.php**

```
<? $makeId=$_GET['make'];
$modelId=$_GET['model'];
echo $modelId;
mysql
$query="SELECT distinct model_year FROM cars WHERE model_make_id='$makeId' AND model_name='$modelId' order by model_year asc";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="year"  onchange="getEngine('<?=$makeId?>',this.value)">
<option>Select year</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$modelId?>><?=$row['model_year']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

**findEngine.php**

```
<? $makeId=$_GET['make'];
$modelId=$_GET['model'];
$yearId=$_GET['year'];
echo $yearId;
mysql
$query="SELECT distinct model_trim FROM cars WHERE model_make_id='$makeId' AND model_name='$modelId' AND model_year='$yearId' order by model_trim asc";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="engine">
<option>Select year</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value><?=$row['model_trim']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You should follow the advice from your [own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175948/do-prepare-statements-secure-your-database) and use parameterized queries. You're completely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Also, trying to pinpoint where the error occurs would help a lot. Posting ~200 lines of code in total is not going to get your question answered very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

As per the definition of getEngine function, it takes 3 parameters but you are passing only 2.

Change below line in findEngine.php

```
<select name="year"  onchange="getEngine('<?=$makeId?>',this.value)">
```

To,

```
<select name="year"  onchange="getEngine('<?=$makeId?>', '<?=$modelId?>', this.value)">
```

Also, avoid using mysql extension as it is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php for the details and alternatives.